# how to access property with hyphen in name in JS JSON

Tags: javascript, json

Im trying to access an element in JSON With Hyphen in the property name

id("main").textContent = jsonData.res.main-result;

but that is causing an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const json = {
  'property-name': 'something'
}

console.log(json['property-name']);
```

Use `jsonData.res['main-result']`